# How to reset filter in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41790532/7453272

How to reset my filter object with ng-click ?
I want return my object with full body.

Comment: can you specify your problem instead of linking another post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will toggle the filter:

```
      $scope.setCatFilter = function(id){
          if($scope.catFilter == id)
              $scope.catFilter = undefined;
          else   
              $scope.catFilter = id; 
      }
```

so the reset function will be

```
      $scope.resetCatFilter = function(){
          $scope.catFilter = undefined;
      }
```

or

```
<span ng-click="catFilter=undefined">reset</span>
```

Comment: I want to reset with another element click